# Como acceder a una variable tipo Connection deSde otra claSe?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

se puede desde una clase tener:

```
Conection cn;    
cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhot:3306/BD","root","pass");
```

//   y desde otra clase, q es la q inserta un registro llamar a la variable de coneccion "cn" ? La idea es tener la clase de coneccion separada de la clase q hace la insercion.

```
PreparedStatement ST;

ST=cn.preparedStatement("");
```

// me da error que no encuentra "cn" como variable q contiene la coneccion,intente tambien importando la claSe pero in exito.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo podríamos hacer de esta manera.

- Inicializar la conexión en su constructor.
- Tener un método para obtener la conexión desde otra clase.
- Y también otro método para hacer la desconexión..

---

```
public class BaseDatosPG {
    private Connection conn = null;

    public BaseDatosPG(){
        String urlDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BD";
        String user = "root", pass = "pass";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDatabase, user, pass);

        } catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Excepción: "+ ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Excepción no encontró driver: "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        return this.conn;
    }

    public void desconectarBD(){
        System.out.println("Cerrar conexión a base de datos");
        if(conn != null){
            try {
                conn.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("No se realizó la desconexión: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Y a la hora de recuperar esa conexión..

```
BaseDatosPG bd = new BaseDatosPG();
PreparedStatement pST = bd.getConnection().preparedStatement("");
```

Comment: ok! lo empece parecido la parte del PreparedStatement me daba error,supongo xq lo intentaba escribir en la clase y no en el main() -(hay manera de, que lo halla podido averiguar x mi cuenta donde iba escrito el PreparedStament ?) .

Comment: También lo podías haber hecho en el mismo método la inicialización de la conexión. Pero supongo que no estarías muy lejos de averiguarlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la palabra reservada static:

```
 public static Conection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhot:3306/BD","root","pass");
```

y accederas desde cualquier otra clase con:

```
ClaseDondeDeclareCn.cn...
```

Comment: hola gracias por responder puse:                                                        
  Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("url","root","pass"); y me tira el error "ilegal start of exppresion" en la linea esa

Comment: agregaste la librería? la url esta correcta?

Comment: Hola! sip!  esta la libreria ya agregada,la url conecta desde la clase q realiza el insert.Lo que necesitaba, era separar ,la parte del insert con la parte de la coneccion.